# Type conversion iterator in C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator

I have type `SDK::TIPAddressDescription` which I don't control and my `THNNetIface` which  is also not controlled enough by me as is generated from `IDL` specification. Also I've wrapped types by iterators to make them workable with STL.

I want to add modifications to existing code:

```
// Update IP addresses of interfaces existing in DB
vector<THNNetIface> modIfaces;
set_intersection(ifaceFirstIter, ifaceLastIter, ipFirstIter, ipLastIter, 
    back_inserter(modIfaces), HNInfoComparator());
```

with the following:

```
// Note: delIfaces is not of type SDK::TIPAddressDescription as expected by STL;
vector<THNNetIface> delIfaces;
set_difference(ipFirstIter, ipLastIter, ifaceFirstIter, ifaceLastIter,
    mod_inserter(delIfaces), HNInfoComparator());
```

where `mod_iterator` acts as converter from `SDK::TIPAddressDescription` type to `THNNetIface` for each element (to satisfy STL requirements) and `back_inserter` at the same time (or compatible with them).

*How to do this type-convertion iterator? Is there existing approaches to do that in Boost-similar libraries?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Boost Iterator and Boost Range have facilities that do this.

- The most generic is `boost::function_output_iterator`

  **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6564d28aa5ff469e)</kbd>** (c++03)

  ```
  auto output = boost::make_function_output_iterator(
          phx::push_back(phx::ref(delIfaces), phx::construct<THNNetIface>(arg1)));

  boost::set_difference(iface, ip, output, HNInfoComparator());
  ```

  **OR**

  **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f99b1e3d6c6b11)</kbd>** (c++11)

  ```
  auto output = boost::make_function_output_iterator(
          [&](TIPAddressDescription const& ip) { delIfaces.emplace_back(ip); });

  boost::set_difference(iface, ip, output, HNInfoComparator());
  ```

---

- <strike>Boost Range `transformed` perhaps with `boost::phoenix::construct<>` could be more elegant</strike> Sadly this option is not available, since `set_difference` requires an output iterator. This was a 
  thinko